# Do I need to DeleteObject to dispose of an HBITMAP* when using [ComImportAttribute()]?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

From [MSDN about IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> It is the responsibility of the caller to free this retrieved resource
>   through [DeleteObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when it is no longer needed.

My question is:

I'm using the `IntPtr` in an `IShellItemImageFactory.GetImage` call where the `IShellItemImageFactory` is decorated with **`[ComImportAttribute()]`**. Do I still need to call `DeleteObject`, or will that cause trouble when the CLR(?) will try deleting it as part of the `Factory`?

Comment: @HansPassant I don't understand your comment. That is exactly what I quoted. My question is what happens when using `ComImportAttribute` - does that make it a bad thing to use DeleteObject or does it not change anything.

Comment: you might want to check out the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) or the now nugeted version https://www.nuget.org/packages/Windows7APICodePack/

Comment: @Mgetz Thanks. But that's what I've been using until now, and is exactly what I'm trying to avoid - using all of that for a little bit of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CLR will **never** automatically release an IntPtr.  It cannot possibly know what specific function needs to be called to release the pointer.  It is entirely up to you to pinvoke DeleteObject().

Comment: OK. Thanks. (I was actually asking this mainly because of another answer of yours [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210723/do-i-need-to-free-resources-when-calling-shcreateitemfromparsingname-from-manage/9211291#9211291) where you state: `it is automatic, just like .NET objects.` and say that Disposing might be `a good way to shoot your foot though`. I thought this will apply here as well. Thanks again.

Comment: That answer was about a COM interface pointer, not an IntPtr.  The CLR knows a lot about interface pointers, starting by it automatically creating an RCW.  You cannot compare the two.

Comment: Sorry for continuing , but the other answer here says I not only have to **DeleteObject** the `IntPtr`, but also **FinalReleaseCOMObject** the `IShellItemImageFactory`. I understand from your other answer that at least that should _not_ be done. Which one is it?

Comment: OK. Never mind. I see he now deleted his answer. Thanks again.